# Could not load type Sitecore.Jobs.Job from assembly Sitecore.Kernel when deploying the JSS site

Tags: jss

This is the command : `jss deploy app -c -d`, I am deploying the newly created jss site in to Sitecore 9.2

```
Error: Could not load type Sitecore.Jobs.Job from assembly Sitecore.Kernel
```

[image]

Comment: Try to install sitecore powershell 5.1

Comment: Tried it, no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade JSS to JSS 12.

Comment: It's already in JSS 12
jss --version
12.0.0

Comment: Right. But that error, is from a Sitecore 9.1 DLL in a 9.2 solution. If you call up your local Sitecore instance, it's likely you will see the exact same error - JSS deploy or otherwise.

Comment: I was able to load the sitecore 9.2  with no issues.

Comment: @sai please mark this answer as accepted if it solved the issue.

Comment: My bad, my previous comment has been misunderstood. This issue still exists, sitecore 9.2 has been loading with no issues, the issue is with JSS deploy.

Comment: Installing Sitecore JavaScript Services 12.0.0 fixed the issue.

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services/120/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services_1200.aspx

Comment: @MarkCassidy kindly release this.

Comment: @sai - please accept the answer from Mark